# Dinner Guests arrangements

Tags: python

This IS a homework problem, but I've been working on it for a while and I don't understand what I am doing wrong. Any help would be appreciated.

> Count the number of ways that N dinner guests can arrange themselves around a round table, according to the following rules:
>
> Initially, all guests are seated at a round table with no empty seats. To encourage conversations, the host asks each guest to stand up, and then sit in one of three chairs: the original chair, one to the left or one to the right.
>
> All guests must sit down.
>
> How many different arrangements of dinner guests are there?
>
> Two arrangements are different if the chair number for any guest differs from one arrangement to the other.
>
> ABCD is different from DABC. However, no one person can move more than two places,
>   I.E BCAD would be invalid because A has moved two place.
>
> The partial solutions are:

```
3 guests can sit in  6 different ways

4 guests can sit in  9 different ways

5 guests can sit in  13 different ways

6 guests can sit in  20 different ways

7 guests can sit in 31 different ways
```

My code is working for up to 5 guests, but for 6 guests, I am getting 19 different arrangements. For 7 guests, I am getting 28 arrangements. I am guessing there is something off with my logic but I can not figure it out.

Here's my code:

```
def dinner_party_arrangements(N):
    import itertools
    if N > 10:
        return('This function is not built for N > 10.')
    else:
        import math
        result=math.factorial(N)
        baseL=[]
        main=list(range(N))
        L=list(range(N+1))
        L.remove(0)
        combos=(list(itertools.permutations(L)))
        for stuff in combos:
            baseL.append(stuff)
        for guests in baseL:
            resultL=list(guests)
            #looks at single tuple
            for num in main:
                a=num
                b=num+1
                c=num+2
                if resultL[num] == a or resultL[num] == b or resultL[num] == c:
                    pass
                else:
                    result=(result-1)
                    break
        if N<3:
            return(result)
        else:
            return(result+N)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's the refactored version of your code, for a better understanding:

```
import itertools
import math

def dinner_party_arrangements(N):
    assert N <= 10, 'This function is not built for N > 10.'
    result = math.factorial(N)
    if N < 3:
        return result
    for guests in itertools.permutations(range(1, N+1)):
        for num in range(N):
            if guests[num] not in (num, num+1, num+2):
                result -= 1
                break
    return result+N
```

I think the problem is that you don't manage the "edges", i.e. position 0 can be occupied by guest 1 (no change), guest 2, (right neighbour) or guest N (the last one, which is the left neighbour). The same goes for the last position on the table. Therefore, the following will work (leaving `import`s aside):

```
def dinner_party_arrangements(N):
    assert N <= 10, 'This function is not built for N > 10.'
    if N < 3:
        return math.factorial(N)
    allguests = list(itertools.permutations(range(1,N+1)))
    result = len(allguests)
    for guests in allguests:
        for num in range(N):
            if guests[num] not in (N if num==0 else num, num+1, 1 if num==N-1 else num+2):
                result -= 1
                break
    return result
```

Also note that I don't use factorial in N>2; I just count the number of permutations that are correct.

Even better, the following uses the lazy nature of the permutations function:

```
def dinner_party_arrangements(N):
    assert N <= 10, 'This function is not built for N > 10.'
    if N < 3:
        return math.factorial(N)
    result = 0
    for guests in itertools.permutations(range(1,N+1)):
        for num in range(N):
            if guests[num] not in (N if num==0 else num, num+1, 1 if num==N-1 else num+2):
                break
        else:
            result += 1
    return result
```

Finally, here's a recursive solution for this. As opposed to your (and other peoples) approach I don't generate every permutation and then eliminate the wrong ones; I create the solutions from scratch. Also, I use 0-based numbering which seems more natural to me:

```
def dinner(gst):
    assert gst > 2  # alogorith doesn't work for < 3 people
    res = []        # result, the list of all possible combinations

    def sub(current, pers):
        if pers == gst:         # base case of recursion; no more person to sit
            res.append(current) # found one combo, add it to result
            return              # and stop here
        for offset in (-1, 0, +1):          # for each move (left, stay, right)
            newpos = (pers + offset) % gst  # compute new position
            if current[newpos] is None:     # seat is not yet taken
                newcurrent = current[:]     # create a copy of current (incomplete) combination
                newcurrent[newpos] = pers   # sit person pos at position newpos
                sub(newcurrent, pers + 1)   # and recurse for the other persons

    sub([None]*gst, 0)  # initialize a combi
    return res
```

then

```
for i in range(3, 8):
    combos = dinner(i)
    print(i, "guests can sit in", len(combos), "ways", combos)
```

yields

```
3 guests can sit in 6 ways [[1, 2, 0], [2, 1, 0], [0, 1, 2], [0, 2, 1], [1, 0, 2], [2, 0, 1]]
4 guests can sit in 9 ways [[1, 2, 3, 0], [3, 1, 2, 0], [3, 2, 1, 0], [0, 1, 2, 3], [0, 1, 3, 2], [0, 2, 1, 3], [1, 0, 2, 3], [1, 0, 3, 2], [3, 0, 1, 2]]
5 guests can sit in 13 ways [[1, 2, 3, 4, 0], [4, 1, 2, 3, 0], [4, 1, 3, 2, 0], [4, 2, 1, 3, 0], [0, 1, 2, 3, 4], [0, 1, 2, 4, 3], [0, 1, 3, 2, 4], [0, 2, 1, 3, 4], [0, 2, 1, 4, 3], [1, 0, 2, 3, 4], [1, 0, 2, 4, 3], [1, 0, 3, 2, 4], [4, 0, 1, 2, 3]]
6 guests can sit in 20 ways [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 0], [5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 0], [5, 1, 2, 4, 3, 0], [5, 1, 3, 2, 4, 0], [5, 2, 1, 3, 4, 0], [5, 2, 1, 4, 3, 0], [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [0, 1, 2, 3, 5, 4], [0, 1, 2, 4, 3, 5], [0, 1, 3, 2, 4, 5], [0, 1, 3, 2, 5, 4], [0, 2, 1, 3, 4, 5], [0, 2, 1, 3, 5, 4], [0, 2, 1, 4, 3, 5], [1, 0, 2, 3, 4, 5], [1, 0, 2, 3, 5, 4], [1, 0, 2, 4, 3, 5], [1, 0, 3, 2, 4, 5], [1, 0, 3, 2, 5, 4], [5, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4]]
7 guests can sit in 31 ways [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 0], [6, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 0], [6, 1, 2, 3, 5, 4, 0], [6, 1, 2, 4, 3, 5, 0], [6, 1, 3, 2, 4, 5, 0], [6, 1, 3, 2, 5, 4, 0], [6, 2, 1, 3, 4, 5, 0], [6, 2, 1, 3, 5, 4, 0], [6, 2, 1, 4, 3, 5, 0], [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 5], [0, 1, 2, 3, 5, 4, 6], [0, 1, 2, 4, 3, 5, 6], [0, 1, 2, 4, 3, 6, 5], [0, 1, 3, 2, 4, 5, 6], [0, 1, 3, 2, 4, 6, 5], [0, 1, 3, 2, 5, 4, 6], [0, 2, 1, 3, 4, 5, 6], [0, 2, 1, 3, 4, 6, 5], [0, 2, 1, 3, 5, 4, 6], [0, 2, 1, 4, 3, 5, 6], [0, 2, 1, 4, 3, 6, 5], [1, 0, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], [1, 0, 2, 3, 4, 6, 5], [1, 0, 2, 3, 5, 4, 6], [1, 0, 2, 4, 3, 5, 6], [1, 0, 2, 4, 3, 6, 5], [1, 0, 3, 2, 4, 5, 6], [1, 0, 3, 2, 4, 6, 5], [1, 0, 3, 2, 5, 4, 6], [6, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]]
```

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my approach.  It's really slow for large n, but it works.

```
from itertools import permutations

def arrange( n ):
    # First, place all your guests (0 - n) into an array
    positions = range( n )

    arrangements = 0
    # Iterate over every possible arrangement of guests
    for arrangement in permutations( positions ):
        # begin by assuming the iteration is "valid", that is, no guest
        # hopped more than one spot
        is_valid = True
        # Now iterate over all your guests
        for i in range( n ):
            # If the guest moved more than one spot, this permutation is
            # invalid and we can throw it out
            pos_dif = abs( arrangement.index( i ) - positions.index( i ) )
            if pos_dif > 1 and pos_dif != n-1:
                is_valid = False
                break
        # Otherwise, the iteration is valid and we can increment our count
        if is_valid:
            arrangements += 1
    return arrangements
```

Answer (score 0):

My approach was similar to the above post:

```
def mydin(n):
    import itertools
    initial_table = range(n)
    poss_tables = set(itertools.permutations(initial_table))
    validTables = []
    for table in poss_tables:
        if isValid(initial_table,table):
            validTables.append(table)
    print len(validTables)
    return len(validTables)

def isValid(initial_table,arrangement):
    size = initial_table[-1]
    for i in range(len(initial_table)):
        if i == size:
            if arrangement[i] in (initial_table[i-1],initial_table[i],initial_table[0]):
                continue
            else:
                return False
        elif arrangement[i] in [initial_table[i-1],initial_table[i],initial_table[i+1]]:
            continue
        else:
            return False
    return True

for n in range(3,11):
    mydin(n)
```

and for my output I got

```
6
9
13
20
31
49
78
125
```